# How to put PHP code in wordpress pagination function (previous_post_link,next_post_link,etc)?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I want to put PHP code in my pagination:

```
<?php next_post_link('%link','<div class="nav-next" title="<?php the_title();?>">Next Post</div>')?>
```

However, the result is I got a text:     ""     instead of the real title post when I hover my pagination link.

How to get my php code works inside that wordpress parameter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for get_the_title. [next_post_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) already makes the title of the next post available, via %title

```
 next_post_link( '%link', '<div class="nav-next" title="%title">Next Post</div>' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use string concatenation and [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) which returns the value rather than echoing it:

```
<?php 
  next_post_link(
           '%link',
           '<div class="nav-next" title="'.get_the_title().'">Next Post</div>'
 )?>
```

Comment: WOW!Thanks a lot Pekka. Very quick and straight!
It's working!

By the way, the ; after get_the_title() is not needed. :)